# Separate the binding values according to a condtion in Ultragrid

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I need to bind a specific values of a `column` to another `column` based on some conditions.

I have four `columns` in my grid, so based on the values of the second `column` I need to prefer binding the values of the third column to the same or fourth `column` (i.e either one) in `Ultragrid`.

In which event can I write this? How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **InitializeRow** event of `UltraGrid`

Try this:

//Code

```
Private Sub grdReport_InitializeRow(sender As Object, e As InitializeRowEventArgs) Handles grdReport.InitializeRow

    If (e.Row.Cells("column1").Value Is "") Then
      //Do ur stuff here
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to use less memory it is better to use the GetCellValue method off the UltraGridRow object rather than accessing the cell directly as the cells are created when necessary and accessing the cell will cause its creation.  There are more details on this in the Memory Usage topic in the help: http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=WinGrid_Memory_Usage.html